# My error validation message for user login used to show on chrome but now it does not

Tags: javascript, c#

When i debug my website's user login page on visual studio and tried to test the error validation for invalid user login, the ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript error message does not show, the page just refreshes itself. Im sorry if im not being specific enough, im trying my best to explain the situation. Do let me know if you need more info.

```
    **This is my aspx.cs codes:**

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Web.Configuration;

    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            static readonly string scriptErrorUserId =
        "<script language=\"javascript\">\n" +
        "alert (\"Error - UserID you keyed in is taken up, please key in another UserID\");\n" +
        "</script>";

            static readonly string scriptErrorField =
            "<script language=\"javascript\">\n" +
            "alert (\"Error - Some fields are empty please fill them up\");\n" +
            "</script>";

            static readonly string scriptSuccessNewAccount =
            "<script language=\"javascript\">\n" +
            "alert (\"Your account has been succesfully created - Thank You!\");\n" +
            "</script>";



            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


            }


            protected void btnSignin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLAzureConnection"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            Type csType = this.GetType();
                    SqlCommand sqlcmd;
                    SqlDataReader rdr;            
                    string strSql1 = "SELECT * FROM Customer ";
                    sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(strSql1, con);
                    rdr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
                    string encryptedPwd = WMASecurity.Encrypt(txtpw.Text);
                    while (rdr.Read() == true)
                    {

                        if (txtUsername.Text == (string)rdr["cCustID"] &&
                           encryptedPwd == (string)rdr["cPassword"])
                        //txtPassword.Text == (string)rdr["cPassword"])
                        {
                            Session["sFlag"] = "T"; //sFlag = "T" means user has logged in
                            Session["sUserId"] = rdr["cCustID"];
                            Session["sName"] = rdr["cName"];
                            Session["sContact"] = rdr["cPhoneNo"];
                            Session["sGender"] = rdr["CGender"];
                            Session["sEmail"] = rdr["cEmail"];
                            Session["sAddress"] = rdr["cAddress"];
                            Session["sPoints"] = rdr["cPoints"];
                            Session["stotalspend"] = rdr["ctotalspend"];
                            string welcomeMsg = "Welcome " + Session["sName"];
                            Master.MasterpageLabel.Text = welcomeMsg;
                            Master.divLogin.Visible = false;
                            Master.divLogout.Visible = true;
                            Master.divUpdate.Visible = true;
                            con.Close();
                            String strUserId = (string)Session["sUserId"];
                            cDataRoutines DROObject = new cDataRoutines();
                            DROObject.cCreateRecs(strUserId);
                            Response.Redirect("Homepage.aspx");
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                   //
                     Session["sFlag"] = "F"; //sFlag = "F" means user has failed to logged in
                     Session["sName"] = "";
                     Session["sUserId"] = "";
                     Session["sAddress"] = "";
                     Session["sEmail"] = "";
                     Session["sContact"] = "";
                     Session["sGender"] = "";                
                     txtUsername.Text = "";
                     con.Close();
                }


            protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLAzureConnection"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            Type csType = this.GetType();
                //Check to ensure that UserId keyed in is not being in used by other Customers
                SqlCommand sqlcmd;
                SqlDataReader rdr;
                string strSQLSelect = "SELECT cCustID FROM Customer ORDER BY cCustID";
                sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(strSQLSelect, con);
                //SqlDataReader reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
                rdr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
                string encryptedPwd = WMASecurity.Encrypt(txtPassword.Text);
                while (rdr.Read() == true)


                    if (txtUserId.Text == (string)rdr["cCustID"])
                    {
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Error", scriptErrorUserId);
                    con.Close();
                        return;
                    }

                    if (txtUserId.Text == "")
                    {
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Error", scriptErrorField);
                con.Close();
                        return;
                    }

                    if (txtAddress.Text == "")
                    {
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Error", scriptErrorField);
                con.Close();
                        return;
                    }

                    if (txtName.Text == "")
                    {
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Error", scriptErrorField);
                con.Close();
                        return;
                    }

                    if (txtEmail.Text == "")
                    {
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Error", scriptErrorField);
                con.Close();
                        return;
                    }

                    if (txtPassword.Text == "")
                    {
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Error", scriptErrorField);
                con.Close(); 
                        return;
                    }

                    // insert new record
                    string strSQLInsert = "INSERT INTO "
                        + " Customer  (cCustID, cName, cPassword, cPhoneNo, CGender, cEmail, cAddress)"
                        + " VALUES (@CustID, @Name, @Password, @Contact, @Gender, @Email, @Address)";
                    sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(strSQLInsert, con);
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustID", txtUserId.Text);               
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);               
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", encryptedPwd);
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", txtContact.Text);
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Genderdropdown.SelectedValue);
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
                    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
                    txtUserId.Text = "";
                    txtPassword.Text = "";
                    txtName.Text = "";
                    txtAddress.Text = "";              
                    txtEmail.Text = "";



                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Success", scriptSuccessNewAccount);

                    // prepare Session variables for newly registered customer
                    Session["sFlag"] = "T";
                    Session["sCustId"] = (string)txtUserId.Text;
                    Session["sName"] = (string)txtName.Text;
                    Session["sContact"] = (string)txtContact.Text;
                    Session["sGender"] = (string)Genderdropdown.SelectedValue;
                    Session["sEmail"] = (string)txtEmail.Text;
                    Session["sAddress"] = (string)txtAddress.Text;

                }
            }`enter code here`


    this is my webconfig file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->`enter code here`
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AlanandguysSQLConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-V6SOBQI;Initial Catalog=AlanandguysSQL;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="AlanandguysSQL (1)ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-V6SOBQI;Initial Catalog=&quot;AlanandguysSQL (1)&quot;;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="AlanandguysSQL (1)ConnectionString2" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-V6SOBQI;Initial Catalog=&quot;AlanandguysSQL (1)&quot;;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="AlanandguysSQL (1)ConnectionString3" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-V6SOBQI;Initial Catalog=&quot;AlanandguysSQL (1)&quot;;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="SQLAzureConnection" connectionString="Data Source=alannguys.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=alannguys;Integrated Security=False;User ID=serverlogin;Password=Alannguys123;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>

    <customErrors mode="Off" />

  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: We could have an idea if you posted a [mcve]. As your question stands, we cannot help you.

Comment: You will need to debug the code yourself. Check the browser's development console for error messages, try to walk through the code, inspect the HTML page for missing scripts, etc. We are not able to take your code dump and run it, you need to provide an [mcve] if you want more help.